# Services submenu disappeared from contextual menu of right click

Tags: macos, finder, services

I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 at my office. Last week, I was still able to right click files or folders and choose services from the bottom of contextual menu. However, after I started my Mac this morning and reopen the Finder, I am not able to see the services submenu after right click. I can only choose the services without using the columns view and click **Finder** > **Services** from the top left.

I typed this command in the Terminial but it did not solve it:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs
```

Is there another other way to make it what it was? Thanks.

[image]

**Edit:**
After rebooting, the problem still exist, but I noticed one thing: the services shows up only on desktop, but not within the finder window.

**Edit 2:**
In addition to desktop, it also appears in icon view, but not in column & list view (which previously do).

I have also tried quiting/force quiting Automator Runner, ScriptMonitor and some other background processes which was not responding from the Activity Monitor, but still no good.

[image]

**Edit 3:**
After some observation, it might be caused by the Adobe CS5 / Creative Cloud / Finder conflict. I have uninstalled CC which I don't use much (needed to share with other people). Will observe some more time to see if it is completely resolved.

Comment: sorry, should have waited for it :)

Comment: Nah, it okay :)

Comment: so the "Reveal in Finder" is missing

Comment: Yes, and some custom services I created, like copy path and delete files permanently... I use them all the time.

Comment: Without those custom services, my workflow would take more time. I can add shortcuts to them, but the most annoying part being not working in the columns view (it perceive the selected folder as opened folder...) It's just weird that something worked for a long time suddenly not working.

Comment: can you find the service files  you made?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26782/discussion-between-pete-c-and-buscar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later it was accompanied with the Spinning Beach Ball of Death. After uninstalling Adobe Creative Cloud it does resolved all problems.

Comment: Another reason I'm glad I never needed Adobe products... ;)

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the exact same bug! I found out, that i was logged out of Creative Cloud. When I logged back in, the Services-menu appeared again in Finder. This is a very weird bug..

Comment: Good to know it! I post it here just in case someone experience it too. :)