# Services menu on right click in Apple Mail missing?

Tags: mail.app, macos, shortcut-menu

In macOS Sierra, Mail app, I select a message and right click. The "Services" selection is missing.

I can select text within a message and right click, seeing the services menu, but I swear this worked before just fine and I've used it a ridiculous amount of times with specific apps.

This: [Services submenu disappeared from contextual menu of right click](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199512/services-submenu-disappeared-from-contextual-menu-of-right-click) did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might need to update your plugins for Sierra (if you use that Mac OS). I had the same issue with Omnifocus clip o iron and had to update it here: https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/clip-o-tron-in-sierra/26977